# Why do some classes have zero sensitivity in a multiclass classification with neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, metrics, multiclass-classification

I am getting a sensitivity equal to zero for 3 classes out of 7 classes. I have fine-tuned a Facial Emotion Recognition model in Keras, and I managed to get an accuracy of around 35%, but sensitivity per class is an important metric for me to look at. It is coming out something like this: [0.96323    0.    0.017543    0.105263    0.    0.    0.11976], which is very confusing to me.

This is the distribution of data across my classes

Class 1: 18.13%
Class 2: 7.72%
Class 3: 12.43%
Class 4: 7.92%
Class 5: 7.58%
Class 6: 14.36%
Class 7: 31.85%

I solved the class imbalance by using the class weights parameter in tensorflow. But I still get some classes with 0 sensitivity.

Can anyone suggest some ways to improve the class sensitivity?

Comment: Zero sensitivity means there are no True Positive Classifications for that class. To further investigate you can look for how the data that should be within those classes is classified instead. Maybe you will find some patterns there, that will allow you to identify the problem.

Comment: @NMme and how can that be done? Sorry, I am a bit new to this.

Comment: During evaluation, only pass data from one of the classes with zero sensitivity e.g. Class 2 and investigate the result. I think creating a histogram of the output with `tf.summary.histogram()` could be a good way to see what the most common miss-classifications are. If you can observe that all examples of class 2 are classified e.g. as class 1 you know that there is your issue. I hope this helps